# Magento 2: remove all default JS for custom theme

Tags: magento2, requirejs, custom-theme, requirejs-config.js

We are creating multiple websites in one magento 2 instance with a custom theme. Those websites are not supposed to be shops. They all are serving one simple page without any of magento's functionality. They are simple one-pagers that exist for SEO purposes.

But unfortunately when I enable the require-js functionality magento keeps loading all the default JS files that hardly anybody needs or knows about.

Is there a way to clear all those files before starting from scratch? All I really need is jquery and maybe a couple more libraries but not all the shop overhead (100+ unused JS files).

Thank you.

Comment: try this ---  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148914/remove-css-and-js-from-new-custom-page-layout-from-header-and-body-magento-2

Comment: Well, this would mean I had to remove each and every file one by one. Not a very suitable way of going forward. I was aware of this method. What I am aiming at is a total reset.

Comment: I think no but check this link in last --- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html#disable_default_js

Comment: did you tried selecting blank as a parent theme for your custom theme

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately current we can't remove loaded js from default inside custom theme